# C++ class with array member with size passed by CTOR

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

Why I cannot have `m_data` array as a member like this?

```
class Array
{
private:
    const int m_capacity;
    int m_data[m_capacity];

public:
    Array(const int capacity = 100);
};


Array::Array(const int capacity /*= 100*/)
    : m_capacity(capacity)
{

}
```

And how I can achieve this without dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: Array with size determined at runtine is spelled [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case the compiler can't know the size of `class Array` and it can't determine size of such object. If objects of indeterminate compile-time size were allowed, the entire language would be different.

However, if you know capacity at compile time, you can write

```
template <int Size = 100>
class Array
{
private:
    int m_data[Size];

public:
    Array();
};
```

Then, to use it, you can do

```
Array<> a; //size = 100
Array<250> b; //size = 250
```

As @Superlokkus mentioned in comment, C++11 `std::array` is just a better implementation with same concept.

Comment: And so mention, `std::array` has been made for just that purpse

Comment: I would also add `static const int m_capacity = Size;` to private section to retain original intention

Comment: @mvidelgauz it is not necessary, because now he can use `Size` instead inside class, and he couldn't use `m_capacity` outside, for `m_capacity` is private

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest use std::array instead of building your own wheel

```
#include <array>
template< unsigned long N >
using Array = std::array<int, N>;
```

And use `Array` as a normal templated class

```
Array<100> arr;
```

If you are keen on 100-sized array, it is even simpler

```
using Array = std::array<int, 100>;
Array arr;
```

Answer (score 2):

Either you can declare a template class like this

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t N = 100>
class Array
{
private:
    const size_t m_capacity = N;
    int m_data[N];

public:
    Array();
};

template <size_t N>
Array<N>::Array() : m_data {}
{
}

int main() 
{
    Array<> a1;
    Array<10> a2;

    return 0;
}
```

Or you should use data member

```
std::vector<int> m_data;
```

instead of the array.

Comment: Thanks, I have just changed `N` to size and I get this error: `error C3867: 'Array<100>::size': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member` Oh, I got it. Because I had a member names `size` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an object whose size is chosen at runtime without dynamic allocation.  You can have it without naked `new`/`delete`; the normal class encapsulating that requirement is `std::vector`.

Alternatively, you can have a family of classes of different sizes.  The normal class for that is `std::array`.